# Is it bad practise to hide rarely used options and provide a button to expand them?

Tags: ios, menu, mobile-application, app

[image: My Current App UI]

If my problem is confusing to you, please refer to the image above.This is regarding an app I'm designing for a local railway.In which, you can search for train schedules.The reason I hide most search options is that I needed to trim the UI from clutter and because most people don't use the advanced options as timings.

Other UI/UX critique is also welcome :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is alright to expand certain content, but provide enough information of what is hidden.

**Right now the user won't know what the button does/displays until he clicks it**.

Take this [Material design - expansion panels](https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#expansion-panels-behavior) example. There is certain information displayed when it is collapsed that shows us what is the hidden information about:

[image]

[image]

---

Maybe something like this (rough design):

[image]

Comment: I like your example better than Material's one with all those actions in something that should be very straightforward

Comment: What I don't understand from Material's examples is why the panels separate when one is expanded.

Comment: Based on other documentation, I think they transform into cards when active. This is a good behavior, because when collapsed, it works fine as an expandable list (or even accordion). But try editing your image and getting all the list items together, and you'll see it gets really confusing, and user may tap on save or open an expandable item. Conceptually, when collapsed, they belong to a group, but once expanded, you go deep one dimension, so the element has an entity of its own. Just guessing, of course

Comment: It makes sense, so it has to do with the Action buttons. Good point! I guess if it is only information displayed there is no need to separate the elements, like [in a list](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_10/assets/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3bl8zNGVqM19TNWM/components_listcontrols_expand2.png).

Comment: Date is also an important field so show it but for timing do as Alvaro shows for date as "today and then angle down " so for time give "Any and angle down".